# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apollo-client, apollo-boost

I am learning apollo. When I run my code it showing this error on my browser I don't know if it is my browser's problem. can anyone help me fix this
Error message

```
./node_modules/@apollo/client/node_modules/optimism/lib/bundle.esm.js
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\bijit\OneDrive\Desktop\wrk\JavaScript\pokemon\node_modules\@apollo\client\node_modules\optimism\lib\bundle.esm.js'
```

my App.js file

```
import React from "react";
import ApolloClient from "apollo-boost";
import { ApolloProvider } from "@apollo/react-hooks";
import PokemonsContainer from "./container/PokemonsContainer";

function App() {
  const client = new ApolloClient({
    uri: "https://graphql-pokemon2.vercel.app/",
  });
  return (
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <main>
        <PokemonsContainer />
      </main>
    </ApolloProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

here is my PokemonsContainer.js file

```
import React from 'react'

function PokemonsContainer(){
    return(
        <p>i am pokemon</p>
    )
}


export default PokemonsContainer
```

i have already installed apollo client and other dependencies i don't know why this error is occurring here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "pokemon",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/client": "^3.3.12",
    "@apollo/react-hooks": "^4.0.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.13.10",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.13.10",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "apollo-boost": "^0.4.9",
    "apollo-cache-inmemory": "^1.6.6",
    "apollo-client": "^2.6.10",
    "apollo-link": "^1.2.14",
    "apollo-link-error": "^1.1.13",
    "apollo-link-http": "^1.5.17",
    "graphql": "^15.5.0",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.11.0",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-hook": "^0.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Try with runnig `npm-install` command

Comment: Did you run npm install apollo-client and the other dependencies? You'll need to install all the dependencies that you want to work with. Example: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@apollo/client

Comment: i already did it

Answer (score 0):

I also faced a similar error. I fixed it by installing

> node-sass

```
npm i node-sass
```

Then I stopped the running npm server and restart it.